# Non-passive, active way of describing photos (or other things) on a wall

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I write audio description for shows/TV and it is usually a firm rule not to use the passive voice, which can be arbitrarily frustrating (like how else are you supposed to say 'the door is locked?')

Anyway, sometimes it comes down to not being creative enough with the language or not knowing enough verbs to express an action in the most appropriate way, which is where I find myself with 'photos on a wall.'

How would I describe that there are photos on a wall without using passive voice, e.g. "Photos of basketball players are stuck to the wall." I can't say "photos of basketball players cover the wall" as that could give the unintended impression that the whole wall is covered with photos whereas it is just a tiny section of the wall.

SO I need a verb instead of 'cover' that could do the job of saying that a few photos are stuck on the wall in active voice.

Any ideas?

Comment: "The wall has photos of basketball players."

Comment: _The door is locked_ is not passive. It's a predicate adjective, like _The door is red_. Obviously the editors don't know what they're doing. Too bad.

Comment: Are sentences like "the door is locked" and "photos are stuck to the wall" passive?  Typically a passive sentence has *to be* and then a past participle.  But in "the door is locked" *locked* is an adjective, not a past participle.  I guess more to the point, is the rule that you can't use *to be* in any sentence?

Comment: What's wrong with "there are photos on the wall"?

Comment: If the audio description simulates seeing the show: *We see a wall of basketball player photos.*

Comment: This question cannot be answered because it is based on a mistake. *Pictures that are stuck to the wall* is no more of a passive construction than  *People who are gone now* is. Just because you have some photos stuck to the wall doesn't mean that any "passive invoice" is involved. It is not. You're confusing simple adjectives with passive participles being used in passive constructions.

Answer (score 3):

*The door is locked* does not display the passive voice. *Locked* is a past participle adjective in a linking verb sentence here. To prove a passive, you would need evidence of an agent: *The door is locked by the janitor (nightly).*

And guess what? Without evidence of an agent, the same goes for *stuck* in *Photos of basketball players are stuck to the wall*. To prove a passive you would need evidence of an agent: *Photos of basketball players are stuck to the wall by the bartender (whenever a new one arrives).*

Try it with *Gum is stuck to my shoe.* (Can you even come up with a reasonable agent?)

Lastly, if you swap in *affixed*, for example, you can show your editors the *OED*:

> **affixed**, *adj.*
> *1.* Fastened, joined, attached; appended; spec. annexed (to a property).
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

If you don’t want to argue with the editors, try: *Photos of basketball players cling to the wall.*

Comment: The agent? A heel, obviously ;)

Comment: @PhilSweet — What a heel!

Comment: "The door is locked" could be passive even without an agent, e.g. "the door is locked every day at sunset; then it is unlocked the next day at noon."

Comment: Evidence of an agent doesn’t need to appear in a sentence *by*-phrase. But without one, only context, of which we have none, will tell. Every day that *I* go to the library at sunset, the door is locked!

Comment: Fair enough. Granted, OP doesn't specify if those imposing the rule on him/her are able to accurately identify the passive voice.

Answer (score 2):

While your sentence is passive voice, it can easily be converted to active: "Photos stick to the wall." This is more specifically called the middle (or [mediopassive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/mediopassive-middle-voice-usage-verbs)) voice. The verb is ergative because it allows this flexibility. However that's not the most idiomatic verb for this context. I would use **hang**: "Photos hang on the wall." (Another ergative verb.)

You can also reword. "The photos on the wall depict basketball players." Or as part of a longer sentence: "…the photos on the wall of basketball players…"

Answer (score 0):

> a firm rule not to use the passive voice, which can be arbitrarily frustrating (like how else are you supposed to say 'the door is locked?')

Fortunately, the people enforcing this rule typically don't really understand what the passive voice is or how to identify it, so you may be able to get away with it sometimes.

> SO I need a verb instead of 'cover' that could do the job of saying that a few photos are stuck on the wall in active voice.

The easiest option is just: **"There are pictures of basketball players on the wall."** In context, it would be obvious that these are photographs, not other works of art.

In informal AmE, "there's" is the usual contraction of "there are" ([see ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/can-we-use-there-is-for-plural-nouns)), so in informal contexts you would likely shorten it to: **"There's pictures of basketball players on the wall."**

Comment: Photos decorate the wall.